# plugin with id com.android.library

Tags: android, libgdx

Trying to import the facebook project as a Gradle project and recieves that error.

This is build document for my project:

(And since stackoverflow wont let me post that code with their "Code Sample"):
http://pastebin.com/dYBmNWgc

And facebook build:

http://pastebin.com/qqGgU0Rr

Comment: It's likely because it's using a gradle plugin that doesn't know about com.android.library plugin (they used to have different ids). Try changing apply plugin: 'com.android.library' to apply plugin: 'android-library'. Or update the gradle plugin version.

Comment: In which build? Android or Parent/Core?